# What does the floating point number $(1.2)$ down the bracket mean?

Tags: physics, quadratics, mathematical-physics

What does the 1.2 on the image mean?

[image: https://imgur.com/VCgoD2p]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where did you find this?

Comment: I'm not sure it's 1.2; it probably is 1,2 which means there are two values for the fraction on the left-hand side, one for the + sign and the other with the - sign in front of the square root.

Comment: I guess it is actually "$1,2$" and means the two solutions of a quadratic equation.

Comment: In the U.S., decimals are indicated by a lower point.  Some places, it is an interpunct, but in some other places, it is a comma.  What do those places use in this circumstance here, I wonder?  ETA: I don't mean to suggest it is an insuperable ambiguity.  I'm just curious.

Comment: As noted in other comments, that is likely a comma being used to separate two values and not a decimal separator.  Lacking further context, I would agree with Peter's assessment that the 1 and 2 are being used to index the two values on the right (on with a plus sign, one with a minus.  For example, if $ax^2+bx+c = 0$, then there are two solutions: $$ x_{1,2} = \frac{-b\pm \sqrt{\Delta}}{2a} \quad\text{can be read}\quad x_1 = \frac{-b+\sqrt{\Delta}}{2a},\ x_2 = \frac{-b-\sqrt{\Delta}}{2a}, $$ where $\Delta = b^2 - 4ac$ is the discriminant.

Comment: @Henry http://www.braeunig.us/space/orbmech.htm

Comment: Oh. That's a 1,2 instead of a 1.2. How stupid i am. Well, thanks for answering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that they are indices 1 and 2 separated by a comma. Thus you have two different expressions. The $\pm$ distinguish between the two expressions:

$$\left( \frac{R_p}{r_{1}} \right)_{\color{red}1}=\frac{-C\color{red}+\sqrt{C^2-4(1-C)(-\sin^2(\gamma_1))}}{2(1-C)}$$

$$\left( \frac{R_p}{r_{1}} \right)_{\color{red}2}=\frac{-C\color{red}-\sqrt{C^2-4(1-C)(-\sin^2(\gamma_1))}}{2(1-C)}$$

It is an application of the $\text{quadratic formula}$. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_formula).

Comment: And this answer may be even more obvious if you consult the text just before the equation...